# Event brite API is not returning address of event

Tags: ios, eventbrite

I am using EventBrite API to fetch events in my iOS app.

I am hitting this GET service
https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?location.address=Indore&token=MY_EVENTBRITE_TOKEN

Here is a response from EventBrite. I want to show events in map but eventbrite is not responding lat. long or address of events.

```
{
"pagination": {
    "object_count": 4, 
    "page_number": 1, 
    "page_size": 50, 
    "page_count": 1
}, 
"events": [
    {
        "name": {
            "text": "San Ildefonso April SET Meeting", 
            "html": "San Ildefonso April SET Meeting"
        }, 
        "description": {
            "text": "Please bring your family, friends and neighbors San Ildefonso's April SET Meeting at 5:30-8:00 Thursday April 14th at Tewa Center. This will be for San Ildefonso's Community only as each community is having their own April meeting and in May we will all come back together to share our progress. \nLook forward to seeing you then! \n  \nBest, \n  \nCarol ", 
            "html": "<P>Please bring your family, friends and neighbors San Ildefonso's April SET Meeting at 5:30-8:00 Thursday April 14th at Tewa Center. This will be for <SPAN>San Ildefonso's<\/SPAN> Community only as each community is having their own April meeting and in May we will all come back together to share our progress.<\/P>\n<P>Look forward to seeing you then!<\/P>\n<P><BR><\/P>\n<P>Best,<\/P>\n<P><BR><\/P>\n<P>Carol<\/P>"
        }, 
        "id": "24038244035", 
        "url": "http://www.eventbrite.com/e/san-ildefonso-april-set-meeting-tickets-24038244035?aff=ebapi", 
        "start": {
            "timezone": "America/Denver", 
            "local": "2016-04-14T17:30:00", 
            "utc": "2016-04-14T23:30:00Z"
        }, 
        "end": {
            "timezone": "America/Denver", 
            "local": "2016-04-14T20:00:00", 
            "utc": "2016-04-15T02:00:00Z"
        }, 
        "created": "2016-03-23T20:49:07Z", 
        "changed": "2016-03-23T21:58:09Z", 
        "capacity": 60, 
        "status": "live", 
        "currency": "USD", 
        "listed": true, 
        "shareable": true, 
        "online_event": false, 
        "tx_time_limit": 480, 
        "hide_start_date": false, 
        "locale": "en_US", 
        "is_locked": false, 
        "privacy_setting": "unlocked", 
        "is_series": false, 
        "is_series_parent": false, 
        "is_reserved_seating": false, 
        "logo_id": null, 
        "organizer_id": "8633327198", 
        "venue_id": "14280432", 
        "category_id": null, 
        "subcategory_id": null, 
        "format_id": null, 
        "resource_uri": "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/24038244035/", 
        "logo": null
    }, 
    {
        "name": {
            "text": "Get Traction: The Virtual Growth Event [Indore]", 
            "html": "Get Traction: The Virtual Growth Event [Indore]"
        }, 
        "description": {
            "text": "Register Now>>\u00a0http://re.tc/wwondecl \nLEARN STRATEGIES, TACTICS & TOOLS FOR GROWTH MARKETING IN 2016 \nIMPORTANT NOTE:\u00a0This is a Virtual On-Demand Event. You will get access to all presentations immediately.\u00a0 \n \nOverview: \nThere\u2019s no denying that growth is hot and here to stay. But despite the buzz, many businesses still don\u2019t have the framework they need to build a successful growth engine. Join a community of data-driven marketers, sales hackers and innovative entrepreneurs who will learn the fundamentals of rapid growth for 2016.\u00a0 \nEvent Features: \n3 days of in-depth learning ( 15 interactive sessions) - covering growth fundamentals, advanced tactics, business development and sales \nConnect with 3K+ founders, growth marketing\u00a0execs and innovation teams \nAll sessions will be recorded and available on-demand \nTopics include:\u00a0 \n\nLean branding hacks and strategy\nEarly-stage growthProduct marketing & UX/UI\nLean management and hiring\nReferral marketing\nCommunity development\nDigital Marketing Best Practices\nSearch engine optimization\nWeb analytics\nSocial media & content marketing\nAffiliate marketing\nDigital advertising & Paid Search\nEmail marketing automation\nGrowth Hacking\nConversion optimization & testing\nMarketplace & viral growth\nGamification\nWeb Scraping\nSales Automation\nHacking partnerships\n\n\u00a0 \nLEARN MORE \n\u00a0 \n\u00a0\u00a0 \nWho should Attend:\u00a0 \nGrowth Hackers\u00a0\u2022\u00a0Growth Marketers\u2022 Founders \u2022 CEOs \u2022 Marketing Directors \u2022 \u00a0Software Engineers\u00a0\u2022 \nProduct Managers \u2022 Small Business Owners \u2022 Marketing Consultants \u2022 Investors \u2022 Mentors \u2022 Entrepreneurs\u00a0\u2022\u00a0Sales Executives \nPARTNERS: \n\n\n\n\n\u00a0 \n\n\n\u00a0 \n\u00a0 \n\n\n\n\u00a0\n\n\u00a0 \n\n\n\n\n\u00a0 \n\n\n\u00a0 \n\n\n\n\n\u00a0 \n\n\n\u00a0 \n\n\n\n\n\u00a0 \n\n\n\u00a0 \n\n\n\n\n\u00a0 \n\n\n\u00a0\u00a0 \n\n\n\n\nIf you would like to learn more about sponsorship packages, please send us an email to\u00a0sponsor@startupsocials.com \nFollow US \nWeb I\u00a0Linkedin I Facebook I\u00a0Meetup\u00a0\u00a0 \n\u00a0 \n\u00a0 \n\u2022 ", 
            "html": "<P><SPAN STYLE=\"font-size: large;\"><STRONG>Register Now&gt;&gt;\u00a0<A HREF=\"http://re.tc/wwondecl\" REL=\"nofollow\">http://re.tc/wwondecl<\/A><\/STRONG><\/SPAN><\/P>\r\n<P><SPAN STYLE=\"font-size: large;\"><STRONG>LEARN STRATEGIES, TACTICS &amp; TOOLS FOR GROWTH MARKETING IN 2016<\/STRONG><\/SPAN><\/P>\r\n<P CLASS=\"p1\">IMPORTANT NOTE:\u00a0This is a Virtual On-Demand Event. You will get access to all presentations immediately.\u00a0<\/P>\r\n<P><OBJECT STYLE=\"line-height: 1.6em;\" WIDTH=\"425\" HEIGHT=\"350\" DATA=\"https://www.youtube.com/v/HqKgXEG9z8k\" TYPE=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\"><PARAM NAME=\"src\" VALUE=\"https://www.youtube.com/v/HqKgXEG9z8k\"><\/PARAM><\/OBJECT><\/P>\r\n<P><SPAN><STRONG>Overview:<\/STRONG><\/SPAN><\/P>\r\n<P><SPAN>There\u2019s no denying that growth is hot and here to stay. But despite the buzz, many businesses still don\u2019t have the framework they need to build a successful growth engine. Join a community of data-driven marketers, sales hackers and innovative entrepreneurs who will learn the fundamentals of rapid growth for 2016.\u00a0<\/SPAN><\/P>\r\n<P><SPAN><STRONG>Event Features:<\/STRONG><\/SPAN><\/P>\r\n<P>3 days of in-depth learning ( 15 interactive sessions) - covering growth fundamentals, advanced tactics, business development and sales<\/P>\r\n<P>Connect with 3K+ founders, growth marketing\u00a0execs and innovation teams<\/P>\r\n<P>All sessions will be recorded and available on-demand<\/P>\r\n<P><STRONG>Topics include:\u00a0<\/STRONG><\/P>\r\n<UL>\r\n<LI>Lean<SPAN STYLE=\"line-height: 1.6em;\"> branding hacks and strategy<\/SPAN><\/LI>\r\n<LI><SPAN STYLE=\"line-height: 1.6em;\">Early-stage growthProduct marketing &amp; UX/UI<\/SPAN><\/LI>\r\n<LI><SPAN STYLE=\"line-height: 1.6em;\">Lean management and hiring<\/SPAN><\/LI>\r\n<LI><SPAN STYLE=\"line-height: 1.6em;\">Referral marketing<\/SPAN><\/LI>\r\n<LI><SPAN STYLE=\"line-height: 1.6em;\">Community development<\/SPAN><\/LI>\r\n<LI><SPAN STYLE=\"line-height: 1.6em;\">Digital Marketing Best Practices<\/SPAN><\/LI>\r\n<LI><SPAN STYLE=\"line-height: 1.6em;\">Search engine optimization<\/SPAN><\/LI>\r\n<LI><SPAN STYLE=\"line-height: 1.6em;\">Web analytics<\/SPAN><\/LI>\r\n<LI><SPAN STYLE=\"line-height: 1.6em;\">Social media &amp; content marketing<\/SPAN><\/LI>\r\n<LI><SPAN STYLE=\"line-height: 1.6em;\">Affiliate marketing<\/SPAN><\/LI>\r\n<LI><SPAN STYLE=\"line-height: 1.6em;\">Digital advertising &amp; Paid Search<\/SPAN><\/LI>\r\n<LI><SPAN STYLE=\"line-height: 1.6em;\">Email marketing automation<\/SPAN><\/LI>\r\n<LI><SPAN STYLE=\"line-height: 1.6em;\">Growth Hacking<\/SPAN><\/LI>\r\n<LI><SPAN STYLE=\"line-height: 1.6em;\">Conversion optimization &amp; testing<\/SPAN><\/LI>\r\n<LI><SPAN STYLE=\"line-height: 1.6em;\">Marketplace &amp; viral growth<\/SPAN><\/LI>\r\n<LI><SPAN STYLE=\"line-height: 1.6em;\">Gamification<\/SPAN><\/LI>\r\n<LI><SPAN STYLE=\"line-height: 1.6em;\">Web Scraping<\/SPAN><\/LI>\r\n<LI><SPAN STYLE=\"line-height: 1.6em;\">Sales Automation<\/SPAN><\/LI>\r\n<LI><SPAN STYLE=\"line-height: 1.6em;\">Hacking partnerships<\/SPAN><\/LI>\r\n<\/UL>\r\n<P>\u00a0<\/P>\r\n<P STYLE=\"text-align: center;\"><SPAN STYLE=\"font-size: x-large; color: #ff0000;\"><STRONG><A HREF=\"http://re.tc/u4vf14h8\" REL=\"nofollow\"><SPAN STYLE=\"color: #ff0000;\">LEARN MORE<\/SPAN><\/A><\/STRONG><\/SPAN><\/P>\r\n<P>\u00a0<\/P>\r\n<P><SPAN><IMG ALT=\"\" SRC=\"https://cdn.evbuc.com/eventlogos/129706179/screenshot20150517at3.48.31pm.png\" WIDTH=\"600\">\u00a0<\/SPAN><SPAN STYLE=\"line-height: 1.6em;\">\u00a0<\/SPAN><\/P>\r\n<P STYLE=\"text-align: center;\"><SPAN STYLE=\"font-size: medium;\"><STRONG>Who should Attend:\u00a0<\/STRONG><\/SPAN><\/P>\r\n<P STYLE=\"text-align: center;\"><SPAN>Growth Hackers\u00a0\u2022\u00a0Growth Marketers\u2022 Founders \u2022 CEOs \u2022 Marketing Directors \u2022 \u00a0Software Engineers\u00a0\u2022<\/SPAN><\/P>\r\n<P STYLE=\"text-align: center;\"><SPAN>Product Managers \u2022 Small Business Owners \u2022 Marketing Consultants \u2022 Investors \u2022 Mentors \u2022 Entrepreneurs<\/SPAN><SPAN STYLE=\"line-height: 1.6em;\">\u00a0<\/SPAN><SPAN STYLE=\"line-height: 20.8px;\">\u2022<\/SPAN><SPAN STYLE=\"line-height: 20.8px;\">\u00a0<\/SPAN><SPAN STYLE=\"line-height: 1.6em;\">Sales Executives<\/SPAN><\/P>\r\n<P STYLE=\"text-align: center;\"><SPAN STYLE=\"font-size: medium;\"><STRONG>PARTNERS:<\/STRONG><\/SPAN><\/P>\r\n<TABLE>\r\n<TBODY>\r\n<TR>\r\n<TD>\r\n<P><SPAN>\u00a0<IMG ALT=\"\" SRC=\"https://cdn.evbuc.com/eventlogos/129706179/softlayerlogo.png\" WIDTH=\"300\"><\/SPAN><\/P>\r\n<\/TD>\r\n<TD>\r\n<P>\u00a0<\/P>\r\n<P><IMG ALT=\"\" SRC=\"https://cdn.evbuc.com/eventlogos/129706179/startupsocialslogo.png\" HEIGHT=\"200\" WIDTH=\"200\">\u00a0<\/P>\r\n<\/TD>\r\n<\/TR>\r\n<TR>\r\n<TD>\u00a0<IMG ALT=\"\" SRC=\"https://cdn.evbuc.com/eventlogos/129706179/traction.png\" WIDTH=\"200\"><\/TD>\r\n<TD>\r\n<P><SPAN><IMG ALT=\"\" SRC=\"https://cdn.evbuc.com/eventlogos/129706179/crowdcast.png\" HEIGHT=\"200\" WIDTH=\"200\">\u00a0<\/SPAN><\/P>\r\n<\/TD>\r\n<\/TR>\r\n<TR>\r\n<TD>\r\n<P><SPAN>\u00a0<IMG STYLE=\"display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;\" ALT=\"\" SRC=\"https://cdn.evbuc.com/eventlogos/129706179/splashu.png\" HEIGHT=\"81\" WIDTH=\"200\"><\/SPAN><\/P>\r\n<\/TD>\r\n<TD>\r\n<P><SPAN>\u00a0<IMG ALT=\"\" SRC=\"https://cdn.evbuc.com/eventlogos/129706179/speakeasy11.jpg\" WIDTH=\"200\"><\/SPAN><\/P>\r\n<\/TD>\r\n<\/TR>\r\n<TR>\r\n<TD>\r\n<P><SPAN>\u00a0<\/SPAN><\/P>\r\n<\/TD>\r\n<TD>\r\n<P><SPAN>\u00a0<\/SPAN><\/P>\r\n<\/TD>\r\n<\/TR>\r\n<TR>\r\n<TD>\r\n<P><SPAN>\u00a0<\/SPAN><\/P>\r\n<\/TD>\r\n<TD>\r\n<P><SPAN>\u00a0<\/SPAN><\/P>\r\n<\/TD>\r\n<\/TR>\r\n<TR>\r\n<TD>\r\n<P><SPAN>\u00a0<\/SPAN><\/P>\r\n<\/TD>\r\n<TD>\r\n<P><SPAN>\u00a0<\/SPAN><SPAN STYLE=\"line-height: 1.6em;\">\u00a0<\/SPAN><\/P>\r\n<\/TD>\r\n<\/TR>\r\n<\/TBODY>\r\n<\/TABLE>\r\n<P STYLE=\"text-align: center;\"><SPAN>If you would like to learn more about sponsorship packages, please send us an email to\u00a0<A HREF=\"mailto:sponsor@startupmonthly.org\" REL=\"nofollow\"><SPAN>sponsor@startupsocials.com<\/SPAN><\/A><\/SPAN><\/P>\r\n<P><SPAN><STRONG>Follow US<\/STRONG><\/SPAN><\/P>\r\n<P><A HREF=\"http://growthmarketingconf.com/\" REL=\"nofollow\">Web<\/A> I\u00a0<A HREF=\"http://linkd.in/1FmBqiw\" REL=\"nofollow\">Linkedin<\/A> I <A HREF=\"https://www.facebook.com/groups/367375373411422/\" REL=\"nofollow\"><SPAN>Facebook<\/SPAN><\/A> I\u00a0<A HREF=\"http://www.meetup.com/Startup-Growth-Experts-SF/\" REL=\"nofollow\"><SPAN>Meetup<\/SPAN><\/A>\u00a0\u00a0<\/P>\r\n<P><SPAN>\u00a0<\/SPAN><\/P>\r\n<P>\u00a0<\/P>\r\n<P><SPAN STYLE=\"font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 20.8px; text-align: center;\">\u2022<\/SPAN><\/P>"
        }, 
        "id": "22127980385", 
        "url": "http://www.eventbrite.com/e/get-traction-the-virtual-growth-event-indore-tickets-22127980385?aff=ebapi", 
        "start": {
            "timezone": "Asia/Calcutta", 
            "local": "2016-03-01T10:00:00", 
            "utc": "2016-03-01T04:30:00Z"
        }, 
        "end": {
            "timezone": "Asia/Calcutta", 
            "local": "2016-08-04T14:00:00", 
            "utc": "2016-08-04T08:30:00Z"
        }, 
        "created": "2016-02-23T20:16:31Z", 
        "changed": "2016-03-31T15:31:33Z", 
        "capacity": 1000, 
        "status": "started", 
        "currency": "USD", 
        "listed": true, 
        "shareable": true, 
        "online_event": false, 
        "tx_time_limit": 480, 
        "hide_start_date": false, 
        "locale": "en_US", 
        "is_locked": false, 
        "privacy_setting": "unlocked", 
        "is_series": false, 
        "is_series_parent": false, 
        "is_reserved_seating": false, 
        "logo_id": "18954683", 
        "organizer_id": "8193977126", 
        "venue_id": "13432572", 
        "category_id": "102", 
        "subcategory_id": "2004", 
        "format_id": "9", 
        "resource_uri": "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/22127980385/", 
        "logo": {
            "id": "18954683", 
            "url": "https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fimg.evbuc.com%2Fhttp%253A%252F%252Fcdn.evbuc.com%252Fimages%252F18954683%252F130614122253%252F1%252Foriginal.jpg%3Frect%3D79%252C0%252C1146%252C573%26s%3D7e34335ecd1a331cf902a2ebf2fad53f?h=200&w=450&s=7c0f35504e73a384677649f935967ef4", 
            "aspect_ratio": "2", 
            "edge_color": null, 
            "edge_color_set": true
        }
    }, 
    {
        "name": {
            "text": "Award Function", 
            "html": "Award Function"
        }, 
        "description": {
            "text": "Social Award\u00a0 ", 
            "html": "<P>Social Award\u00a0<\/P>"
        }, 
        "id": "22843762308", 
        "url": "http://www.eventbrite.com/e/award-function-tickets-22843762308?aff=ebapi", 
        "start": {
            "timezone": "Asia/Calcutta", 
            "local": "2016-04-20T11:00:00", 
            "utc": "2016-04-20T05:30:00Z"
        }, 
        "end": {
            "timezone": "Asia/Calcutta", 
            "local": "2016-04-20T14:00:00", 
            "utc": "2016-04-20T08:30:00Z"
        }, 
        "created": "2016-03-11T09:54:03Z", 
        "changed": "2016-03-11T09:54:05Z", 
        "capacity": 250, 
        "status": "live", 
        "currency": "USD", 
        "listed": true, 
        "shareable": true, 
        "online_event": false, 
        "tx_time_limit": 480, 
        "hide_start_date": false, 
        "locale": "en_US", 
        "is_locked": false, 
        "privacy_setting": "unlocked", 
        "is_series": false, 
        "is_series_parent": false, 
        "is_reserved_seating": false, 
        "logo_id": null, 
        "organizer_id": "9910149827", 
        "venue_id": "13828449", 
        "category_id": "104", 
        "subcategory_id": "4002", 
        "format_id": "100", 
        "resource_uri": "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/22843762308/", 
        "logo": null
    }, 
    {
        "name": {
            "text": "PRODUCT LAUNCHING", 
            "html": "PRODUCT LAUNCHING"
        }, 
        "description": {
            "text": "AGRICULTURE PRODUCT LAUNCHING ", 
            "html": "<P>AGRICULTURE PRODUCT LAUNCHING<\/P>"
        }, 
        "id": "22831220796", 
        "url": "http://www.eventbrite.com/e/product-launching-tickets-22831220796?aff=ebapi", 
        "start": {
            "timezone": "Asia/Calcutta", 
            "local": "2016-04-20T17:00:00", 
            "utc": "2016-04-20T11:30:00Z"
        }, 
        "end": {
            "timezone": "Asia/Calcutta", 
            "local": "2016-04-20T20:00:00", 
            "utc": "2016-04-20T14:30:00Z"
        }, 
        "created": "2016-03-11T08:08:02Z", 
        "changed": "2016-03-11T08:08:04Z", 
        "capacity": 500, 
        "status": "live", 
        "currency": "USD", 
        "listed": true, 
        "shareable": true, 
        "online_event": false, 
        "tx_time_limit": 480, 
        "hide_start_date": false, 
        "locale": "en_US", 
        "is_locked": false, 
        "privacy_setting": "unlocked", 
        "is_series": false, 
        "is_series_parent": false, 
        "is_reserved_seating": false, 
        "logo_id": null, 
        "organizer_id": "9910149827", 
        "venue_id": "13825732", 
        "category_id": "199", 
        "subcategory_id": null, 
        "format_id": "10", 
        "resource_uri": "https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/22831220796/", 
        "logo": null
    }
], 
"location": {
    "latitude": "22.719569", 
    "within": "17.6554610994", 
    "longitude": "75.857726", 
    "address": "Indore"
}
```

}

Can anyone help me out for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include **Expansions** parameter into your requested url to get address of an Event from Event Brite.
So your requested url like below:

https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?location.address=Indore&expand=organizer,venue&token=MY_EVENTBRITE_TOKEN